# Querying associated images in one table after querying products from another

Tags: php

I used this code to connect to a database and fetch results.  This worked perfectly until i tried to work in another query to the images table to get associated images.  I'm not very experienced with OO programming.  So hopefully someone can see where ive gone wrong and help me out.

```
<?php 
    global $__CMS_CONN__;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ecom_products";
    $stmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));

    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {

        $imagesql = "SELECT * FROM ecom_product_images where id = $row->id && where primaryImage = '1'";
        $imagestmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($sql);
        $imagestmt->execute(array($id));
        $imageName = $imagestmt->fetchObject();

        echo '<a href="'.URL_PUBLIC.$row->id.'">'.$row->productNm.'</a>'.$imageName;

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your SQL query:

```
$imagesql = 'SELECT * FROM ecom_product_images where id = ' . $row->id . ' AND primaryImage = "1"';
```

Have you declared before `$id` variable ?

Have you got any errors with your code ?

If your `primaryImage` column is `int` type then skip apostrophes in query

```
primaryImage = 1
```

if `enum` then it is ok.

Comment: why the downvote? This will rectify an error in the OPs code. +1

Comment: This is cool...thanks guys, ill try them now and come straight back to you.  Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

You need not OO programming, but SQL one.

```
SELECT p.*, imageName 
FROM ecom_products p, ecom_product_images i 
WHERE p.id = i.id AND primaryImage = 1;
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` not better here ?